# Uncaught TypeError: ace.acequire is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ace-editor

I have used ng2-ace-editor for one of the components and trying to run test cases using `ng test` command. But due to some reasons, it is throwing `Uncaught TypeError: ace.acequire is not a function` error.

Here's my .spec.ts file code:

```
import { NewModule } from './new.module';
import {AceEditorModule} from 'ng2-ace-editor';
import 'brace';
import 'brace/mode/json';
import 'brace/ext/language_tools';

describe('NewModule', () => {
  let component: NewModule;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Module>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ MaterialModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, 
        HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AceEditorModule
      ],
      declarations: [ NewModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NewModule);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I do not know how to tackle this. Somewhere I got to know that brace is the dependency and need to install this. I do install brace, but it is not working. I tried giving dependencies file in scripts in angular.json, but it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/ace.js",
   "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/ext-language_tools.js",
   "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/mode-javascript.js",
   "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/mode-typescript.js",
   "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/mode-json.js",
   "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/theme-eclipse.js"
]
```

Because of this other spec files are not running, and karma is throwing the below mentioned error. Please suggest me what I need to do.

```
Uncaught TypeError: ace.acequire is not a function
    at language_tools.js:1954
    at Object../node_modules/brace/ext/language_tools.js (language_tools.js:1955)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and fixed it by adding the code blow in xx.component **.ts** file not **.spec.ts** file.

```
import 'brace';
```

Comment: I have imported the above code in my file, as you can see it's there in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I had this in my code:

```
    const { Search } = ace.acequire("ace/search");
```

I replaced it with:

```
    const { Search } = ace.require('ace/search');
```

Assuming you just have this libs (no ng2-ace-editor):

```
npm install ace-builds --save
npm install @types/ace --save-dev
```

and you import `ace` this way in your ts code:

```
import * as ace from 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace';
```